# angularjs attribute name not compiled

Tags: angularjs, compilation, attributes, directive

I'm trying to generate an attribute name like this :

```
name="id{{myScopeId}}"
```

This perfectly works on most cases, but when I do this on an element which already have a custom directive, it doesn't work anymore, and the result is only "id".

This custom directive applies on a file input element and handles the file name.

This will work, and result is

`name="file5" : <input name="file{{myId}}" type="file" />`

This won't work, result is

`name="file" :   <input name="file{{myId}}" type="file" file-handler="fileName" />`

Here's the jsfiddle with example :
http://jsfiddle.net/gubrb/1/

You'll need `firebug` or similar to see generated attribute name.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with your directive definition. As i look at you directive definition, the definition of scope property as object hash creates a new Isolated scope. As per directive [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive),

> {} (object hash) - then a new 'isolate' scope is created. The
>   'isolate' scope differs from normal scope in that it does not
>   prototypically inherit from the parent scope. This is useful when
>   creating reusable components, which should not accidentally read or
>   modify data in the parent scope.

Since in your case you are using object hash, a new scope gets created for the html element which does not inherit from the parent scope.

I have created a new fiddle that fixes this problem by creating a 2 way binding between the parent scope property and directive isolated scope property. See the fiddle in action here http://jsfiddle.net/FhM2c/2/

Some relevant part of the fiddle are

```
 <input name="file{{myId}}" type="file" file-handler="fileName" file="myId"/><br />
```

and the directive

```
 scope : {
            fileHandler : '=',
            myId:'=file'
        },
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer.
It seems obvious now but I wouldn't be able to find out